# 32-bit PNG loading in .NET

Tags: .net, graphics, image

I haven't written any code yet, but I've encountered a similar problem before. Hopefully things have changed since the last time I visited it.

I'm trying to do my own image conversion for games into a special OpenGL image format.

In order to perform the conversion correctly, I need all pixel data and more importantly, i need all the alpha channel data (all 8bits per pixel).

Does the System.Drawing.dll in .NET support full 32-bit alpha transperency loading?

Will I be able to walk the alpha channel with all information retained in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Drawing supports any image formate GDI+ does (PNG-32 included), and getting that information is possible.

Look in to System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel or LockBits

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.  You should get an image with PixelFormat set to Format32bppArgb, then when you call LockBits, you can get to the data with the Scan0 property of the returned BitmapData object.